# ExpressJS: What do I do when redis is down?

Tags: node.js, express, node-redis

The code in question: [app.js](https://github.com/achan/didgomezscore/blob/master/app.js)

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('There was an Error ' + err);
});

// do stuff

redisClient.quit(function(err, res) {
  console.log('closing redis client.');
});
```

I'm trying to use [node_redis](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) to connect to Redis from my node.js app. However, I'm not too sure how to handle the case where Redis is down.

I've got a bunch of `client.on('error', function(err) {})`'s but they never seem to be called. Is that the proper way to handle it? Am I calling it wrong?

I've just started using redis/node/express, so please excuse my ignorance.

**EDIT** As Vadim helped me realize, it seems that I am actually properly catching the error with `client.on('error')` in app.js. However, it's [**my routes**](https://github.com/achan/didgomezscore/blob/master/routes/index.js) that cannot catch the errors when redis is down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since node_redis is asynchronous, the `redisClient.on('error')` callback isn't being called in time before I started to send other commands to `redisClient`.

The way I fixed this issue was by putting "success" code in the `redisClient.on('connect')` handler, which would only be called after redisClient has successfully connected. And my fallback code in `redisClient.on('error')`.

You can see more about how I fixed this problem [in this github changeset](https://github.com/achan/didgomezscore/commit/0176fb3730d2bde04eb11b01ff0c6e82e5f25aed).

Answer (score 0):

I think the [`end`](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis#end) event is what you need.

> client will emit end when an established Redis server connection has closed.

**Update:**

If you are using node.js >= 0.8.0 you can use the [domain module](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) functionality for catching errors in asynchronous code.

You can use the [connect-domain](https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain) module for your express/connect application. It allow you to throw an error in asynchronous code and catch it with your error handler.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that I am actually properly catching the error with `client.on('error')` in app.js. However, its [my routes](https://github.com/achan/didgomezscore/blob/master/routes/index.js) that cannot catch the errors when redis is down. Any ideas?